# Wide screen resolution in VirtualBox

Tags: drivers, virtualbox, windows-7, resolution, screen

I've installed Windows 7 in VirtualBox hosted by Ubuntu. After the installation in Windows 7 I can't see the resolution I need (wide screen). I have only the 4:3 (1024x768 etc.)

How can I fix this? Do I need to install the drivers for my laptop as usual? How to force it to detect my laptop screen type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to install the Virtual Box Guest Additions.

Comment: From the menu? Host+D? Yes. No changes.

Comment: Did you installed them Under Windows Safe Mode and enabled 3D experiemntal when installing?

Comment: Installing Guest Additions properly helped. Thanks.

Comment: For the benefit of others, installing guest additions requires not just doing it from the host menu, but also opening the virtual CD in the guest and running the appropriate installer for your guest OS.  It may "Autorun" in some operating systems but not all.